# ASP.NET how to select checkbox list items with comma separated string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a checkedlistBox `cblHobbies`

```
StringBuilder hobbies = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
foreach (ListItem li in cblHobbies.Items) {
    if (li.Selected) {
        hobbies.Append(li).Append(", ");
    }
}
string hobby = hobbies.ToString().TrimEnd(' ').TrimEnd(',');
```

I am storing hobby in SQL Server database as Varchar(MAX).

When the user edit his profile i want all the hobbies get selected already.

My Question is how to select checklistbox items from a comma separated list  **efficiently**? (in respect of number of iterations)

Comment: Fyi, a nicer way: `string hobby=String.Join(", ", cblHobbies.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i=>i.Selected));`

Comment: But never store multiple informations in one value in your database. Instead store every selected item in it's own record. So this comma separated string does not belong in the database.

Comment: Thanks @Tim :) i will use that. But i can't change DB now.

Comment: However, aren't you mirco optimizing things? What are you trying to optimize at all? If you have read the value from database you can use a simple loop to select them. It's extremely efficient.

Comment: Ok well i thought it can't be optimized much as well. No worries. Thanks @Tim. But i am having trouble deducing code for selecting it from text without using if else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summarizing my comments:

- You can use following readable one-liner instead of your `StringBuilder`-loop:

  ```
  string hobby = String.Join(", ", cblHobbies.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                                             .Where(i=> i.Selected));
  ```
- Never store multiple informations in one value in your database. Instead store every selected item in it's own record. So this comma separated string does not belong there. Normalize your Database.

  - That's much more
    efficient
  - allows easier queries
  - avoids corrupt data
  - etc. ...

However, aren't you mirco optimizing things? If you have read the value from database you can use a simple loop to select them. It's very efficient.

```
string hobby = GetHobbyFromDB();
string[] hobbies = hobby.Split(new []{", "}, StringSplitOptions.None);

foreach (ListItem li in cblHobbies.Items)
    li.Selected = hobbies.Contains(li.Text);
```